# apache nifi S3 PutObject stuck

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

Sorry if this is a dumb question, very new to nifi.

Have set up a process group to dump sql queries to CSV and then upload them to S3. Worked fine with small queries, but appears to be stuck with larger files.
[image: nifi screenshot]

The input queue to the PutS3Object processor has a limit of 1GB, but the file it is trying to put is almost 2 GB. I have set the multi-part parameters in the S3 processor to be 100M but it is still stuck.

So my theory is the S3PutObject needs a complete file before it starts uploading. Is this correct? Is there no way to get it uploading in a "streaming" manner? Or do I just have to up the input queue size?

Or am I on the wrong track and there is something else holding this all up.

Comment: The screenshot suggests that the large file is in PutS3Object's input queue, and PutS3Object is actively working on it (from the 1 thread indicator in the top-right of the processor box).  Does it error out?  Anything in logs/nifi-app.log?

Comment: Thanks. Turns out upload speed from prod servers is much worse than from QA (go figure). Make your comment an answer and I can close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot suggests that the large file is in PutS3Object's input queue, and PutS3Object is actively working on it (from the 1 thread indicator in the top-right of the processor box).

As it turns out, there were no errors, just a delay from processing a large file.